# Unable to pass value to InArgument NativeActivity

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have `custom activity` derived from `NativeActivity`.

`ToEmailAddress` always `null` even though i am passing it when invoking workflow.

Could not figure out why !!!

```
public InArgument<string> ToEmailAddress { get; set; }
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
{
    var email = ToEmailAddress.Get(context);
}
```

Invoking

```
string emailAddress = "aaa@test.com";
Dictionary<string, object> inputs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
inputs.Add("ToEmailAddress", emailAddress);

WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(customerWorkflow, inputs);
wfApp.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
var email = context.getValue(this.ToEmailAddress);
```

if this doesn't work please do check if in your workflow you have passed following parameter to the custom activity